# Prepared Statement Primary Key store seed 1 and increment

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, prepared-statement

Okay, so I just started JDBC with derby client and I'm kind of new with it.
I set column ID as primary key with int as it's data type. However, I'm not sure if I should include `myStatement.setString(1, ?);` because I thought it should Auto Increment but it looks like it's not doing it.

Here's my Grab file details:

```
create table "ADMIN1".STUDENTPERSONALDETAILS
(
ID INTEGER not null primary key,
STUDENTID VARCHAR(10) not null,
LASTNAME VARCHAR(50) not null,
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(50) not null,
MIDDLENAME VARCHAR(50) not null,
PLACEOFBIRTH VARCHAR(200) not null,
DOB VARCHAR(50) not null,
GENDER VARCHAR(4) not null,
CIVILSTATUS VARCHAR(7) not null,
RELIGION VARCHAR(15) not null,
NATIONALITY VARCHAR(20) not null
)
```

How can I correct my `PreparedStatement` or My Table in such a way that adding of value for column ID will be automatic so that I can start `setString(2, studentID)` and avoid getting error about the number of columns not matching with what was supplied?

Here's my code:

```
addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                String myDbUrl = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Enrollment"; //stores url to string
                String userName = "admin1";
                String Password = "admin1";
                    Connection myDBConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(myDbUrl, userName, Password);
                String myQuery = "INSERT INTO STUDENTPERSONALDETAILS"
                        + "(STUDENTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,MIDDLENAME,PLACEOFBIRTH,DOB,GENDER,CIVILSTATUS,RELIGION,NATIONALITY) "
                        + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";

                String adminissionNo ;
                String studentID = tfStudentId.getText().toString();
                String lastName = tfLastName.getText().toString();
                String firstName = tfFirstName.getText().toString();
                String middleName = tfMiddleName.getText().toString();
                String placeOfBirth = tfPob.getText().toString();
                String dateOfBirth = listDOB.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String gender = listGender.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String civilStatus = listCivilStatus.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String religion = listReligion.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String nationality = listNationality.getSelectedItem().toString();

                PreparedStatement myStatement = myDBConnection.prepareStatement(myQuery);

                    myStatement.setString(2, lastName);
                    myStatement.setString(3, firstName);
                    myStatement.setString(4, middleName);
                    myStatement.setString(5, placeOfBirth);
                    myStatement.setString(6, dateOfBirth);
                    myStatement.setString(7, gender);
                    myStatement.setString(8, civilStatus);
                    myStatement.setString(9, religion);
                    myStatement.setString(10, nationality);

                boolean insertResult = myStatement.execute();
                if(insertResult == true)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Added Information");
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Encountered an error while inserting data");
            }
            catch(SQLException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
            }
        }
  });
```

Is it necessary to include `myStatement.setString(1, integervaluehere)` for Primary Keys? Isn't it supposed to autoincrement?

I'd appreciate any explanation because I just started learning the basics of `PreparedStatements` recently.

I tried counting the columns and tried 10 and 11 lines of `myStatement.setString()`, but still can't get it to insert data because of mismatch.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I'm not sure if I should include myStatement.setString(1, ?); "* - No, the `studentid` field isn't required at all for insert statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set the primary identifier column to autoincrement. Since your query already excludes the primary key, you then only have to change the [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) indexes to match the number of parameters in your query [starting from one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString-int-java.lang.String-).

Since you have 10 columns in addition to the primary `ID` column, your `PreparedStatement` might look something like the following:

```
PreparedStatement myStatement = myDBConnection.prepareStatement(myQuery);
myStatement.setString(1, studentId);
myStatement.setString(2, lastName);
myStatement.setString(3, firstName);
myStatement.setString(4, middleName);
myStatement.setString(5, placeOfBirth);
myStatement.setString(6, dateOfBirth);
myStatement.setString(7, gender);
myStatement.setString(8, civilStatus);
myStatement.setString(9, religion);
myStatement.setString(10, nationality);
```

Note that you do not need to have the instruction, `myStatement.setInt(1, primaryId);`, once you have changed the primary key in your table to auto-increment. However, if you elect to keep the primary key as non-autoincrementing, then you must explicitly specify the primary key value and provide a parameter in your query to insert that data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mention 'auto increment' explicitly.
Or you can write your own java code to track the Id for each table and whenever you ask the method to give the ID it will return lastID + 1.

But, I think now you can go with auto_increment option.

Comment: 'Or you can write your own Java code' is a terrible recommendation. The autoincrement needs to take place at the server. There's no reason to write two statements where one will do, or to ship data in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to autoincrement you need to say so in the column definition, and you haven't.

I don't know what 'default 1' in your title is supposed to mean, as you haven't mentioned it in your question, but you can't have a default value *and* autoincrement. It doesn't make sense.

I don't know what 'store seed 1' means either, in your edit.

When you have a column with a default value you want to rely on, or autoincrement, you don't mention it at all in the INSERT statement, so there is no positional argument to set.

Comment: thanks. It's now working. I had to add "generated always as identity" like CREATE TABLE Tablename(ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,....). Is there any other alternative of making it auto increment instead of putting "generated always as identity" Any shorter version of it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered AUTO_INCREMENT, as every man and his dog has been saying here?

Answer (score -1):

If you're using MySQL Workbench, which if you're not, I highly recommend because it just works. You have to choose Auto-Increment as a characteristic of that column. If you want your column to auto increment, when creating columns in your database, check the option Auto-Increment, sometimes written as AI.

Comment: *Non sequitur.* He needs to specify autoincrement regardless of the tool, and he should not do so 'generally when creating columns'. You can only do it on one column per table.

Comment: The sentence about MySQL Workbench remains irrelevant.

Comment: @EJP My apologies on the 'generally' part. I ended up structuring the sentence in a misleading way. Additionally, I was only pointing this out as another alternative. If he specifies this in his database, he no longer needs to do this in his code as the database column now has this property. There was no need of marking this comment down.

Comment: You don't know who marked this *answer* down, but the part about MySQL Workbench remains irrelevant.